# JAVA AES 256 Decrypt

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt with AES some data. I've been given a 256 bit key and 16 byte IV like these:

```
  String key = "Hh1s1f4T2mpN3yCh4ngeL8t3r\\.Thxpp";

  int[] v = {11, 1, 555, 222, 241, 21, 11, 33, 35, 91, 45, 6, 14, 30, 22, 234};

  String IV = Arrays.toString( v );
```

I've been told the padding should be PKCS7 but when I init the cipher with `AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING` it says: `Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING`

If I use `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` I get `Illegal key size` but I've checked that the key size is 32.

```
  public static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String encrypted) {
    try {
        System.out.println( "Key size: " + key.getBytes("UTF-8").length ); 

        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting an `IllegalKeySize` exception with `AES-256`, check to ensure you have the [JCE Unlimited Cryptographic Strength Policy files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) installed in your active JVM. They are required for any AES key length over `128 bits`.

(PKCS #7 padding scheme is [effectively equivalent to PKCS #5 in Java](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/12569) (the block size differs in the spec definitions), but Java never added the PKCS #7 name to its list, so using `PKCS5Padding` is correct.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this solved the problem. It's funny, our production environment does include these libraries much like other people have reported. Difference being production is using OpenJDK vs dev using Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

First see the answer by @Andy.

If you are getting an "Illegal key size" error then the key size is incorrect, you need to figure out why by debugging. Create a variable for the UTF-8 key

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

and display it as hex, that way you can see exactly what it happening.

Inline conversions are essentially impossible to debug.

PKCS#5 padding is a subset of PKCS#7 padding and in every instance it is the same, PKCS#5 is just a name holdover from DES by lazy developers.

[PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7):

> PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8 byte) block size. In practice the two can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use bouncy castle as a provider for PKCS7PADDING.

Comment: In this case PKCS5 is just a naming issue, the name was not updated to PKCS7 when AES was added to the DES code. Both names are for all intents and purposes the same.