# How to Encrypt the string using AES256 algorithm in c# and decrypt the same in java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes

I want the code for Encrypt the string using c# and when the encrypted string is sent to the java function it has to decrypt the same.I want the code for encryption in c# and decrypt code in java.

Comment: Rather than just downvote I'll tell you why you're getting downvoted.  You need to show what you've tried - you need to have attempted it and show what you have that doesn't work.  This site isn't here to do people's homework/jobs for them.  I would expect there are plenty of resources out there if you google 'How to encrypt a string in c#'.  Same probably for the reverse in java.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow stack overflow guidelines for asking questions as @GPW said,
Anyways, here are some examples from SO of what you need, [C# AES 256 Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400884/c-sharp-example-of-aes256-encryption-using-system-security-cryptography-aes/7468039#7468039), [Java AES 256 Decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235976/java-aes-256-decrypt)